# zserge/lorca ui.Eval returns no value

Tags: javascript, html, go

Using `github.com/zserge/lorca` to pass HTML variables to a go func. 
When using lorca's `Eval` method to extract my variables, I'm not getting any returned vlaue.

My code

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"

    "github.com/zserge/lorca"
)

var (
    ui1        lorca.UI
    HTML_entry string = `
<html>
    <body>
        <input hidden type="text" name="MYVAR" value="testVal">
        <input type="submit" onclick="golangfunc()"
    </body>
</html>
`
)

func main() {
    ui1, _ = lorca.New("data:text/html,"+url.PathEscape(HTML_entry), "", 480, 320)
    ui1.Bind("golangfunc", golangfunc)
    defer ui1.Close()
    <-ui1.Done()
}

func golangfunc() {
    htmlvar := ui1.Eval(`document.getElementsByName('MYVAR').value`).String()
    fmt.Println(htmlvar)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByName()` returns a collection of elements, not a single element. I would suggest using `document.getElementById` or `document.querySelector` to get a single element matching the query, then you would be able to get `.value` from it.